# Responsive height Plotly&Django&Python&Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, plotly

i need to make chart height inherited (100% parent)

You want the chart to take up 100% of the height and 100% of the width of the modal window

What are the ways to solve the problem?

My code:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

ticks = list(range(1, int(data['x'])+1))

fig = go.Figure()

for key, val in data['dict'].items():
    fig.add_scatter(x=ticks, y=val, name=key)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=ticks,
        ticktext=ticks,
        title_text='x'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title_text='y'
    ),
    autosize=True,
)

return plot({'data': fig}, config={'responsive': True}, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

My template:

```
<div class="modal-graphic modal fade" id="Graphic" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% autoescape off %}
                    {{ graphic }}
                {% endautoescape %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My result:
[Modal window](https://prnt.sc/vicU6sBUIsHi)